# Which is the difference between "cd ~ ." and "cd . ~"

Tags: command-line

I tried `cd . ~` in terminal and I saw the same result as when I type `cd ~ .`

I want to know how this is done. Or better to say what is the **priority** of the arguments which comes **after a command**?

Comment: What was the same result. You would only get the same result when in your home directory. Try the same example from another directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You saw the same result because I'm sure that you test those commands from your home directory which is `/home/your_username` equivalent with `~` - see [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html), or `$HOME` environment variable. To test properly, you should use:

```
cd / ; cd . ~
```

and:

```
cd / ; cd ~ .
```

In general if you use:

```
cd first_directory second_directory
```

you will change the shell working directory to `first_directory`, not to `second_directory`, so the second argument in the `cd` command is ignored (see also `help cd` to understand better).

And the `.` (dot) in this case is equivalent with the path of the shell current working directory which is given by `pwd` command (see [Commandline shortcut for current directory similar to ~ for home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25813/147044)).

So `cd . ~` is equivalent with `cd .` which is equivalent with `cd $(pwd)` and `cd ~ .` is equivalent with `cd ~` which is equivalent with `cd $HOME`.

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin, you'll find the corresponding man page in `man bash` if you're using bash of course

Comment: @SylvainPineau Sorry, I use [this function](http://askubuntu.com/a/439411/147044). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It gives the same result because you're running them from your home directory. Try moving to /tmp to observe a different behaviour.

Only the first positional parameter of the `cd` command is taken into account:

```
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]
```